# libGDX delay between animations

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
    if (Intersector.overlaps(Object.getBoundingCircle(), myWorld.getGround())) {
        batcher.draw(DownpAni.getKeyFrame(runTime), Object.getX(),
                Object.getY(), Object.getWidth(), Object.getHeight());
    }else {
        batcher.draw(JumpAni.getKeyFrame(runTime), Object.getX(),
                Object.getY(), Object.getWidth(), Object.getHeight());
    }
```

I have an object that hold to animations, one when it touch the ground, the other when it leave it. I use the above code the determine when the each animations will appear, the problem is, I don't know how to increase the amount of time of the DownAni before it change?
Can anyone help me with how to delay the change between animations?

Comment: i can not test it now sorry Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not test it but if I understand what you want to do, because my English is not very good, this is a simple ejmplo could be improved but I think that is what you want

//varible class;

```
float deltaYourExc = -1f;
float deltaYourTime = 5f;
```

.

```
 if  ( Intersector . overlaps ( Object . getBoundingCircle (), myWorld . getGround ()) || (deltaYourExc <= deltaYourTime && deltaYourExc != -1))  { 
        batcher . draw ( DownpAni . getKeyFrame ( runTime ),  Object . getX (), 
                Object . getY (),  Object . getWidth (),  Object . getHeight ()); 

    //delta is delta in render
    deltaYourExc += delta;
    if(deltaYourExc >= deltaYourTime){
    deltaYourExc = -1f
    }

    }else{ 
        batcher . draw ( JumpAni . getKeyFrame ( runTime ),  Object . getX (), 
                Object . getY (),  Object . getWidth (),  Object . getHeight ()); 
    }
```